# Grails with JSF2: WAR cannot run on Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, grails, jsf-2

I'm using the jsf2 plugin for my app.
Running the app with "run-app" it works fine.

But when I deploy the war to a clean Tomcat 6, this error occurs:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: web.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.doc4web.grails.jsf.facelets.GrailsResourceResolver': org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageResourceLoader' is defined
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.ReflectionUtil.decorateInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:252)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:582)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.<init>(ApplicationAssociate.java:215)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.<init>(ApplicationImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl.getApplication(ApplicationFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.getApplication(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:130)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:252)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:335)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageResourceLoader' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
    at org.doc4web.grails.jsf.facelets.GrailsResourceResolver.<init>(GrailsResourceResolver.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.ReflectionUtil.decorateInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:233)
    ... 36 more
```

**For additional info:**

I had to copy the JSF-API (Mojarra 2.0.2) libs to the Tomcat lib folder. Otherwise the *javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory* could not be found.

Comment: I found a bad implementation in the jsf2 plugin. The GrailsResourceResolver.java uses always the GroovyPageResourceLoader. But this ResourceLoader is for loading gsp's from a specific folder during development mode (see javadoc of grails) and is looks like it is not instantiated within a deployable war. I will try a bugfix at this point.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate plugin fork available in google code: [jsf4g](http://code.google.com/p/jsf4g/)

The jsf2 plugin will not work in production mode because the reference to the value groovyPageResourceLoader is available only in development mode Ref- [grails-1.x](http://grails.org/doc/1.1/ref/Plug-ins/controllers.html)

The forked plugin has a fix for it, but that will not work for Grails2.x which needs a fix yet.